# Configure log level in Application Insights for Worker Service applications

Tags: azure, console-application, azure-application-insights, .net-5

There is a NET5 console app that is logging from warning and above. This is the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/worker-service#net-corenet-framework-console-application) followed but it is not working to log information types. It does log warnings. How to change the log level to information?

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        var startup = new Startup();

        startup.ConfigureServices(services);

        var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        var executor = serviceProvider.GetService<IExecutor>();

        await executor.ExecuteTestsAsync();
    }
}

public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public Startup()
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton(Configuration);
        services.AddLogging();
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.AddSingleton<IExecutor, Executor>();
    }
}

    public Executor(ILogger<Executor> logger)
    {
        logger.LogInformation("Hello");//Not logged in AppInsights
        ...
```

appsettings.json

```
{
    "ApplicationInsights":
    {
        "InstrumentationKey": "putinstrumentationkeyhere"
    },
    "Logging":
    {
        "LogLevel":
        {
            "Default": "Information"
        }
    }
}
```

Also tried this:

```
services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder => loggingBuilder.AddFilter<Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights.ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>("Category", LogLevel.Information));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the log level for application insights seperately:

```json
{
    "ApplicationInsights":
    {
        "InstrumentationKey": "putinstrumentationkeyhere"
    },
    "Logging":
    {
        "LogLevel":
        {
            "Default": "Information"
        },
        "ApplicationInsights": {
            "LogLevel": {
                "Default": "Information"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ilogger#create-filter-rules-in-configuration-with-appsettingsjson))